# $(window).on("load",fn) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to check if the website resources are loaded properly.
To test if it works I put into the index.html a wrong CSS file.

If I put the following code in the **Javascript file**, that is included in the head, the message "CSS missing" doesn't appear.

```
$(window).on("load",function () {
   console.log("loaded")
   $("link").on("error",function(){
      console.log("CSS missing");
   });
});
```

Instead, if I put the following code at the **end of the body** in the index.html, the message loading error is printed

```
<script>
    $("link").on("error",function(){
        console.log("loading error");
    });
</script>
```

I need the Javascript file working, what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE**: Using $(document).ready(fn) also not work.

I can't include the javascript at the end of the body because the same script also monitors the page loading time. I need something that is executed at the end of the body with the javascript included in the head.

---

**SOLUTION** without jQuery: I used `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn())` instead of `$(document).ready(fn)` and now all it's working properly.
Why? I don't know.

Comment: You waited for the `load` event on `window` and the `error` event on the `<link>`(s) happened before that. There’s pretty much no reason to wait for `load` ever; the best place to put scripts is generally at the end of `<body>`. This script only has to go after the `<link>`s in `<head>`, though.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn())` is incorrect and equivalent to `fn()`. (Which, in turn, will work like I said if the script is already after the `<link>` elements.)

Answer (score 1):

Loading error appears because the code is executed during the parsing of file, but the file might not be downloaded yet. Try using instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not working, I can't include the javascript at the end of the body because the same script also monitors the page loading time.
I need something that is executed at the end of the body with the javascript included in the head.

Comment: do you want javascript to monitor javascript loading time? <-- that's not possible. otherwise, this is a perfectly valid solution.